# How To Integrate Activiti Modeller Into own Web Application

Tags: activiti, wavemaker

I am very new with activiti and as a part of my project development i need to separate out activiti-modeller from activiti explorer and integrate it with my own web application.

Can anyone give me the steps in detail of how to perform the required activity.

I am using wavemaker 6.5 to develop my application

I went through the source code of activiti explorer but couldnt make out which part to use and how to use it.

Comment: Can I recommend reposting this after reading through [this](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing the question to fit SO guidelines. As is this question will only attract down and close votes.

Comment: I have a solution which worked in Netbeans, it may help you as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218832/integrate-activiti-modeler-using-maven

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy to extract the KisBPM Modeler from the Activiti Explorer.

Extract the following from the source tree into your web application:

- resources/editor.html
- resources/plugins.xml
- resources/stenclset.json
- webapp/editor
- webapp/api
- webapp/explorer
- webapp/libs
- editor (THIS IS THE EDITOR SOURCE IF YOU NEED TO MODIFY IT)

Make sure you add a dependency to activiti-modeler in your webapp pom.xml (this will bring import the restlet classes).
Create a custom root restlet to map your inbound calls (use explorerRestApplication as a template)
Add the restlet declaration to your web.xml

I think that's about it.
We successfully extracted the KisBPM editor for use in an embedded environment that used a custom portal implementation.

Cheers,
Greg@BP3