# Integrate Activiti Modeler with my own Web Application

Tags: java, maven, activiti

I am trying integrate activiti modeler with my web application. My application include some jar modules and three war modules. One of war module i would like to integrate with activiti modeler. I found this tip [How To Integrate Activiti Modeller Into own Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426532/how-to-integrate-activiti-modeller-into-own-web-application) . I have done from this topic but this hasn't worked for me. I get 404 error from ServerServlet.

This is my configuration:
web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- Application class name -->
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.activiti.rest.explorer.application.ExplorerRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mymodule/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-modeler</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Of course I extracted the sources.

this is log:

```
20:27:48,191 ERROR [STDERR] sty 12, 2015 8:27:48 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-01-12    20:27:48    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8080    GET /workflow/service/editor    id=10001    404 0   0   1   http://localhost:8080   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like you exposed the modeler REST endpoint.
Try the following web.xml settings:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- Application class name -->
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.activiti.rest.modeler.application.ModelerRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- Catch all service requests -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```